# C++ | Left button detection on GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, button, click

I am currently in a problem related to **C++** and **GNU/Linux**. Despite searching forums, I can't find exactly what I need to use. I require detecting the moment when the left button is actuated and released as well.
It would help me a code block (if possible commented and specifying which libraries were used) where, when the left click is pressed, the message *"pressed"* is printed by console and, when it is released, it is printed the *"released"* message.
Based on that I would be able to understand and adapt it.

I am new to StackOverflow. If you notice that I made a mistake, please let me know so I can avoid it in future questions. **Thank you!**

*Additional note: It must be possible to detect the action of pressing/releasing anywhere on the screen, not just in the window.*

Comment: On Linux, you have: a) the native system console, b) terminal emulators running in X, c) native X applications. Both of them have completely different ways of interacting with the mouse (and at least one of these has no way of interacting with the mouse on this level, so you'll be out of luck). Have you decided in which environment your program will be running? That, it seems, will be the starting point for your efforts.

Comment: It would be necessary to answer this question to know what library you use to create a window in the first place. E.g. if you use opengl, there is an opengl function to do query cursor interaction.

Comment: I do not use any graphic library. C ++ is not one of the main languages ​​in which I work. I only put it into practice for the development of experimental applications and for my own use. This is why, at least so far, I work with applications that run on terminal (terminal that runs on X, not the native one). In case this data is relevant to solving the problem, I use XFCE as a graphical environment in Manjaro Linux.